# using jQuery .ajax & .text() to load template to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, templates

i've inherited some code that I'm not sure I fully understand...
we're building a cordova app that uses micro templates
and this particular piece of code has me slightly confused :

```
this.loadExternalTemplates = function(templateElements, index, callback) {
        var self = this;
        if (index >= templateElements.length) {     
            callback();
        } else {
            // Load each of the templates into DOM
            var $currElement = $(templateElements[index]);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : $currElement.attr("src"),
                dataType : 'text',
                timeout : 3000,
                success : function(template) {
                    // Write the template to script tag
                    $currElement.text(template);

                    // Iterate / loop to load next template
                    self.loadExternalTemplates(templateElements, ++index, callback);
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    helper.alert("Error occured. Please try again.", error);
                }
        });
    }
};
```

the loadExternalTemplates() function variable is called by the following:

```
this.onDeviceReady = function() {
        var self = this;
        // Load all referenced templates
        self.loadExternalTemplates($("script[type='text/html']"), 0, function() {

            // Initialize the sammy object
            self.initSammyBindings();
        });
};
```

in our main.html we have the script / template tags like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="about-template" src="templates/about.tmpl.html"></script>
```

The code works as it is (ie templates are loaded), but i'm not completely following the logic.

I understand the following :

- scripts with `type="text/html"` are ignored by / hidden from the browser since `"text/html"` doesn't mean anything in a script tag
- the call within onDeviceReady() function uses jQuery to get all scripts with `type="text/html"` and loads them to the  loadExternalTemplates() function (as the templateElements variable)
- the ajax call uses the `src` value of each of the script elements to load the contents (html) via GET
- the jQuery .txt function is used to add the html to the DOM script tag

What I don't understand is

- why the jQuery .text(text) method is used instead of the .html() method ?  doesn't .text strip out the html ? (again it's working, so obviously not, but i'm not fully getting why)
- wouldn't it be more efficient to use jQuery .load() instead of .ajax() ?
- why load all templates to the DOM at the same time ? doesn't that defeat the purpose of having templates ?
- why loop that way (surely there's a better `for each()` or `for()` loop methodology ) - just bad coding or something i'm missing ?
- is there a better (standard?) way of loading templates to the DOM ? on demand ?

Comment: Generally speaking you don't want to block user actions with loading... as it makes your app feel slow; so if you load each template only when needed; you'll be incurring a momentary pause each time... loading them all at once would presumably prevent this.

Comment: it looks like they've favoured synchronously blocked iterations instead of a loop full of asynch calls to prevent the callback from being fired prematurely. - This could be overcome with a deferred promise system. (in jQuery 1.10) http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/